# Characteristics of Odd Square Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$  is an $n \times n$ real matrix, where $n$ is odd, show that $A^2 \neq -I$. In this case $I$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argue by contradiction and take the determinant.

Comment: Proof by contradiction: Assume that $A^2 = -I$, then $-A A = I$. Do I take the det of A or -A? Then negative sign is throwing me off.

Comment: Yes. If $A^2=-I$, then taking the determinants gives $0 \leq \det(A)^2 = (-1)^n = -1$ which is absurd.

Comment: Thanks :) don't know why I couldn't see that.